# JavaScript functions are not interpreted when using PivotTable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pivot, pivot-table

I have integrated PivotTable.js on my web application. The pivot table is shown normally but in some first columns and rows, functions are written and it is not interpreted (See the screenshot) This is an example of a function written:

```
function each(iterator, context) { 
   var index = 0; 
   try { 
       this._each(function(value) { 
           iterator.call(context, value, index++);
        });
   } catch (e) {
      if (e != $break) throw e;
   }
 return this;
 }
```

These are screenshots taken from the result:

[pivot_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIR8T.png)

[Pivot table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoKhe.png)

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./pivot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./tips_data.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./pivot.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#output").pivotUI(
    $.pivotUtilities.tipsData, {
      rows: ["sex", "smoker"],
      cols: ["day", "time"],
      vals: ["tip", "total_bill"],
      aggregatorName: "Sum over Sum",
      rendererName: "Heatmap"
    });
});

</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

THe issue is referenced officially here: https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/708

As i understand, no out-of-the-box solution yet.